# Alternative to ssing linear least squares for solving a matrix equation

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, generalized-least-squares

Assume we have the following matrix equation:

$$
\Delta Y = \frac{\partial Y}{\partial X}\Delta X
$$

where,

$Y$ is n-dimensional vector, $\frac{\partial Y}{\partial X}$ is (n,m) dimensional, and $\Delta X$ is m-dimensional vector.

$Y$ and $\frac{\partial Y}{\partial X}$ are known and we solve for $\Delta X$ using least squares. This is done by:

$$
\Delta Y = \Delta X^{T}\frac{\partial Y}{\partial X}
$$
We could think of it as a multivariable regression, but is not really since we are not doing any predictions or trying to infer causality, but we are just using the least squares as a nummerical method. However, there are still errors from approximation. Final goal is to construct $\hat{X} = (1+\Delta X)X$.  Apart from least-squares, what other methods can one use to solve this?

Comment: Your formula is not least squares and it's not a solution so something's amiss here.  The notation is particularly confusing, because universally $\partial$ is used for derivatives.  If you really are in a situation where least squares is the solution, then what kinds of "other methods" could you have in mind and why would you even want to consider them?